# If $G$ is an infinite graph where $v_{i,j}$ is joined with $v_{k,i+j}$ for all $k,i,j$ then is the chromatic number of G always infinite?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is an infinite graph with vertices labelled as $v_{i,j}$ such that $i,j$ are positive integers (so we assume that there are denumerable many vertices of the graph). For any two positive integers $i,j$ we join the vertex $v_{i,j}$ with all the vertices $v_{k,i+j}$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}.$

Is the chromatic number of the graph $G$ necessarily infinite?

Comment: If someone has seen results closely related to this, then it will be helpful if he or she can share the references with me. Thank you.          - Adi.

Comment: I've got a *deja vu* that I saw this question here on MO earlier, but I have no idea of how to find it now...

Comment: To clarify, is there a vertex $v_{i,j}$ for -all- positive integers $i,j$? So $G$ is uniquely defined?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I finally think I know how I came across this example: back in early 2018 I attended two lectures given at my university by prof. Janos Pach, and it was probably there where he spoke about this graph; unfortunately I do not have any way to verify this assertion about the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chromatic number is indeed infinite.

Assume that there is a proper coloring in finitely many colors. Denote by $S_i$ the set of colors of the vertices having the form $v_{k,i}$ (for some $k$). There are two equal sets, say $S_i$ and $S_j$ with $i<j$. Then the color  of $v_{j-i,i}$ lies in that set, and therefore is also a color of some vertex $v_{k,j}$; but those vertices are adjacent.

Comment: Very nice! This is possibly the easiest explicit example of the triangle-free graph with infinite chromatic number. Is it possible to describe which finite triangle-free graphs are it's subgraphs?

Comment: @FedorPetrov $G$ contains all the *shift graphs*, which explains why the chromatic number is infinite.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $G$ contains a copy of the $n$th *shift graph*, $G_n$.  These are a classic construction of (finite) triangle-free graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number.  The vertices of $G_n$ are all intervals $[i,j]$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq n$.  Two intervals $[i,j]$ and $[k,\ell]$ are adjacent if $j=k$ or $\ell=i$.  It is well-known that $G_n$ has chromatic number  $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$.

Now, let $f:V(G_n) \to V(G)$ be defined by $f([i,j])=v_{j-i,i}$.  Clearly, $f$ is an injective homomorphism, and so $G_n$ is a subgraph of $G$ for all $n$.  Thus, $G$ has infinite chromatic number. This answers a question of Fedor Petrov asked in a comment to Ilya Bogdanov's answer.  Actually, the proof that the shift graphs have unbounded chromatic number is the same argument given in Ilya's answer.

Comment: It not only contains the shift graphs, but is their inductive limit (a union union if they naturally embed to each other).

Comment: @FedorPetrov Indeed. $G$ is really just the 'infinite' shift graph.

Comment: But the question remains: which finite triangle-free graphs are subgraphs of the infinite shift graph, in other words, may be realized by segments?

Comment: As observed by my friend Dragomir Grozev, this graph has a very interesting property: this graph is triangle free, but it contains an n-cycle for each positive integer n which is greater than 3.